# Mongodb c++ driver - linking error: using deprecated boost::stystem::get_generic_category()

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost

I have successfully installed and run mongodb on my macbook pro with 
the c++ driver, but when I am trying to do the same on a computer in 
school (need to do lengthy simulations) I encounter some errors. The 
database itself works nicely, but when I try to compile my program I 
get a lot of these errors:

```
/chalmers/users/X/thesis/libs/mongo-cxx-driver-nightly// 
libmongoclient.a(spin_lock.o): In function 
`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)': 
spin_lock.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to 
`boost::system::get_system_category()'  spin_lock.cpp:(.text+0x50):
undefined reference to  `boost::system::get_generic_category()'...
```

I have downloaded, built and tried boost versions 1.4.8, 1.4.7 and 
1.44.0. As I understand get_system_category() and 
get_generic_category() are both deprecated and replaced by the same 
method name with the "get" dropped. However, on my macbook I use boost 
1.4.7 and it works.. 
I have tried both nightly and latest 2.0 version of the c++ driver. I 
still get the same error. The computer in school is a RedHat 
Enterprice Linux Server. It doesn't have libboost_system in the /usr/lib folder. Since I don't have root access I have 
downloaded and built the libraries needed (boost, libcurl) and I am 
pointing to those in by makefile:

```
path = ./build/  

Ipath = -I/../mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0/mongo/ - I/.../boost_1_44_0/ 

Lpath = -L/.../mongo-cxx-driver-nightly/ -L/.../boost_1_44_0/stage/lib -L/.../curl/lib 

libs = -lboost_system -lmongoclient -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lcurl  

db: sdc.o main.cpp 
        g++ main.cpp $(path)sdc.o $(Ipath) $(Lpath) $(libs) -o $  (path)db  

sdc.o: ../controller.h ../controller.cpp 
        g++ -c ../controller.cpp -o ./build/sdc.o $(Ipath)
```

Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone see what I am doing 
wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that you have build the mongo db library `libmongo.a` against the locally installed version of boost and not against the version of boost that you have downloaded.

Comment: @evnu : Yes, I think you are on the right track. I have used a precompiled version of the libmongoclient.a. Probably it's compiled  using some other version of boost. I tried with 1.35 and than it compiled for the first time. However I got a strange error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 
'boost::thread_interrupted'. I googled on it and someone else had the same problem: https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/5ecb157325332c3a. In one answer Chris Westin implies that the driver (v1.8 of the mongoclient driver) was built with boost 1.42. Trying it now..

Comment: 1.42 worked! Talk about wasted 2 days..

Comment: Now you found the solution... probably you can close it down then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with boost version 1.42..